# What's the difference between flutter_local_notifications and awesome_notifications?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

What's the difference between [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) packages for notification?

After reading through docs and repository I understood, that historically **awesome_notifications** had Push-notification feature built-in and no **firebase_messaging** was needed. But that raised issues as people used both **awesome_notifications** and **firebase_messaging**, which led to problems when used in conjunction.

So the author of **awesome_notifications** removed Push-notification and kept it local.

Which leads to a question: if **awesome_notifications** is now a plugin for *local notifications*,  what does it have now that **flutter_local_notifications** doesn't have?

So why would we need **awesome_notifications** plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to reach the creator of **awesome_notifications** plugin and he answered on this question. To let others know here's his answer:

> The philosophy behind awesome and flutter_local are totally opposed.
> Flutter_local just translates the native functions to Flutter, and
> you're going to need to do everything on your own. But there are some
> things that you’re not able to do only using dart, and you're going to
> struggle with them, such as badge management, interception of
> notification events, etc.
>
> Awesome works by creating a middleware between native and flutter,
> handling the native complexity as much as possible to let the
> notification implementation in your app be as transparent as possible.
> It's not only about differences between Android and iOS, but also
> between Android distributions.
>
> And awesome_notifications has a lot more features than flutter_local
> and covers a lot more services surrounding notifications, such as
> schedules and badge management.
>
> They are not the same; in fact, they are very different.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that awesome_notifications just adds some bells and whistles on flutter_local_notifications which is more minimalist. If you want to do the customization yourself use local_notifications, if you want something with more style out of the box use awesome_notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please tell have you used **awesome_notifications**? I see that it hasn't been updated for 5 months, whereas **flutter_local_notifications** has more frequent updates and very recent. I'm just afraid that if I choose the first one it could be outdated and that would require to still migrate to better maintained one.

Comment: I didn't use it, I stuck with local_notifications for the same reason. If there's some code in awesome notifications you like you can always go in and pull it out from the open source repo, or if you're really keen you could help maintain awesome_notifications repo - but from what I gather there's a lot of moving pieces with all the supported platforms.

Comment: not clear a answer

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference between `awesome_notifications` and `flutter_local_notifications` is:

`awesome_notifications` is not compatible with `firebase_messaging` and you need to use `awesome_notifications_fcm` instead to send cloud based push notifications. And `awesome_notifications_fcm` is not completely free. In free version there is a watermark shown. You need to pay to get rid of this watermark.

This is explained in `awesome_notifications_fcm` like this:

Local notifications using Awesome Notifications are always 100% free to use. And you can also test all push notifications features on Awesome Notifications FCM for free, Forever.

But to use Awesome Notifications FCM on release mode without the watermark [DEMO], you need to purchase a license key. This license key is a RSA digital signature, validated with private and public keys in conjunction with plugin versionings and your App ID / Bundle ID. Because of it, once the license key is generated for your app, its forever. It will never expires and do not require internet connection to be validated.

Answer (score 1):

`awesome_notification` is only compatible with `awesome_notification_fcm`, and `awesome_notification` is not free.

In my experience using `awesome_notification`, it is easy to use. It provides additional callbacks like

1. dismiss notification callback
2. created notification callback
3. on display notification callback

and `flutter_local_notification` doesn't have that feature.

Actually it is free but with a watermark.
I have never seen the watermark.  Is it bothersome in the apps or not?

Can anyone show the watermark image ?